# How to compare two TFS labels while ignoring Deleted Files

Tags: tfs, label, compare

I am aware of the change in TFS 2010 to include deleted files in Labels.

From Microsoft:

> "In TFS 2010, the decision to add deleted items to labels was intentional, and helps with many scenarios where a Get operation is performed to return to the state of the repository at the point in time which the items were labeled.
>   The use of merge with labels is also greatly improved in TFS 2010 with deleted items in labels."

What is unfortunate about this "enhancement" is that when I compare two labels in TFS, the deleted files and folders on that label are considered in the results.  This makes it difficult to truly compare the differences between two labels.

For example:

- create 'label_1'
- delete a file
- create 'label_2'

If I compare 'label_1' and 'label_2' I would like to see the deletion of the file.  Instead TFS reports that there are no differences since 'label_2' still contains the deleted file information.

Is there a way with TFS 2010 to compare two labels and ignore the deleted items?  This seems like such an obvious request and I was initially very surprised with my compare results.

Thanks,

~ bill

Answer (score 1):

Using [TFS-Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) 'Label Sidekick' you can compare two labels and see the file that you 've deleted.

Sidekick will not explicitly present you with the info that the file was deleted, you still have two advantages compared to the display you get in VS:

- deleted file is shown --> so now you know this file is different between the labels
- the changeset with which the file was checked-in is shown. --> If you then open the changeset you 'll reveal fact that the check in was a delete.